# Ошибка при попытке ввода числа в textBox

Tags: c#, winforms, ввод, textbox

У меня есть форма, которая считывает два числа ("a" и "b") и после нажатия на кнопку "Ввод" (button1) число "а" возводится в степень "b" и результат отображается в определенной вкладке.

[image: Вид формы]

При запуске программы, при попытке ввести число, появляется следующая ошибка: `System.FormatException: "Входная строка имела неверный формат.`

Строку, где возникает проблема, я обозначил. Вопрос в том, **как можно исправить данную ошибку?**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Exercise5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
         public double a, b, ras;

         public Form1()
         {
              InitializeComponent();
         }

         private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             a = int.Parse(textBox1.Text); //здесь отображает ошибку
             b = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
         }

         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             ras = Math.Pow(a, b);
             textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(ras);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: избавьтесь от события textBox1_TextChanged(закомментируйте содержимое) и вставьте его в событие button1_Click в самое начало

Comment: Оказывается, все так просто должно быть)) Разобрался!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //убираем содержимое в button1_click
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        b = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        ras = Math.Pow(a, b);
        textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(ras);
    }
```